# Get selected item from first spinner and send to string request URL

Tags: android, json, android-studio, url, spinner

I have tried send selected item from first spinner and i want second spinner show if first spinner selected and send data to string request URL but failed. Example I've been selected number 1 on first spinner and second spinner showing based string URL which already send from first. like this http://192.168.43.66/json/kota/1 and more

```
public String DataIDProvinsi;

private ArrayList<String>id_provinsi;
private ArrayList<String>nama_provinsi;
private ArrayList<String>id_kota;
private ArrayList<String>nama_kota;
private ArrayList<String>id_kecamatan;
private ArrayList<String>nama_kecamatan;


private JSONArray result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    nama_provinsi = new ArrayList<String>();
    id_provinsi = new ArrayList<String>();
    id_kota = new ArrayList<String>();
    nama_kota = new ArrayList<String>();

   TxtDataProvinsi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtDataProvinsi);

    spinner_provinsi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_provinsi);
    spinner_kota = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_kota);
    spinner_jk = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_jk);

    TxtIdProvinsi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtIdProvinsi);


    spinner_provinsi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id){

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>parent){

            TxtIdProvinsi.setText("");
        }
    });
    spinner_kota.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id){

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>parent){



        }
    });



    TxtIdKota = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtIdKota);



    TxtTglLhr = findViewById(R.id.TxtTglLahir);

    findViewById(R.id.TxtTglLahir).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    getDataProvinsi();
    getDataKota();

}



private void showDatePickerDialog(){
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            this, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    String tanggal = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;
    TxtTglLhr.setText(tanggal);
}

public void getDataProvinsi(){
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
   pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Menunggu...");
  //  showDialog();


    StringRequest stringRequestProvinsi = new StringRequest("http://192.168.43.66/json/provinsi/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONObject(response);

                result = j.getJSONArray("result");

                getNamaProvinsi(result);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    //      hideDialog();
        }
        },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequestProvinsi);

}

public void getDataKota(){


  DataIDProvinsi = spinner_provinsi.getSelectedItem().toString();


    StringRequest stringRequestKota = new StringRequest("http://192.168.43.66/json/kota/"+DataIDProvinsi, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONObject(response);

                result = j.getJSONArray("result");

                getNamaKota(result);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         //   hideDialog();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequestKota);

}

public void getNamaProvinsi(JSONArray j){
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonProvinsi = j.getJSONObject(i);
          id_provinsi.add(jsonProvinsi.getString("id_provinsi"));
            //nama_provinsi.add(jsonProvinsi.getString(ProvinsiActivity.TAG_NAMA_PROVINSI));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   spinner_provinsi.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegisterActivity.this,

    R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, id_provinsi));
}

public void getNamaKota(JSONArray j){
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonKota = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //id_kota.add(jsonKota.getString(KotaActivity.TAG_ID_KOTA));
            nama_kota.add(jsonKota.getString("nama_kota"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  spinner_kota.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegisterActivity.this,
    R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, nama_kota));
}

private void showDialog(){
   if(!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog(){
    if(pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you provide more information about your questions. you said you want to get the data for second spinner when you select data in first spinner but you don't implement anything for this.